# PrivateRoute, HOC in React-Router still redirecting to login after Authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, next.js, react-router-dom

I am trying to leverage the state from redux store to a HOC to allow or deny a user in my *app e.g. a Private Route.

I am following the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) from React-Router, and it half works. My problem is when I go to the URL or refresh the newly authenticated route, I get redirected if  **wasn't** authenticated. Clicking through the navbar works, see my gif below.

*I am also using Next.JS, but couldn't get there routing system to work with Semantic-UI-React. Which is why I am using React-Router.

[image]

This is my full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { logInUser, logOutUser } from '../store/index'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Switch,
 Route,
 Redirect,

 withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

import LinkNavWithLayout from './LinkNavWithLayout'
import Index from './home'
import Profile from './profile'
import Dashboard from './dashboard'
import Login from './login'
import Register from './register'

class App extends Component {
 static getInitialProps({ store, isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser }) {
  return { store, isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser }
 }

 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
   isLoggedIn: false
  }

 }

 render(){
  const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;

 console.log("pages/index this.props ", this.props);
  let navBars = [
   { name: "Home", path: "/"},
   { name: "Profile", path: "/profile"},
   { name: "Dashboard", path: "/dashboard"},
   { name: "Log in", path: "/login"},
   { name: "Register", path: "/register"}
  ];
```

My HOC PrivateRoute Component:

```
  function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
   return (
    <Route
     {...rest}
     render={({ location }) =>
      isLoggedIn ? (
       children
      ) : (
        <Redirect
         to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: location }
         }}
        />
       )
     }
    />
   );
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />
```

And I am using it for `/profile` and `/dashboard` routes

```
     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      >
      <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile /></LinkNavWithLayout>
     </PrivateRoute>

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
     >
      <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>
     </PrivateRoute>

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props}/>}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={() => <Register />}
     />

     <Route component={({ location }) => <p>Sorry but the page <h1>{location.pathname.substring(1)} </h1> Page, Could Not be found</p>} />
    </Switch>
    </>
  )
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { isLoggedIn } = state
 return { isLoggedIn }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ logInUser, logOutUser }, dispatch)

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App))
```

Thanks in advance! I've been stuck for a while so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you using for your authentication? You need to store your auth state across pages loads - and to load it into your redux store on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that your redux state or any state for that matter. Will not persist on reload since it is a single page application.
Not without local storage.

When we grab info from local storage to put into state. It's called hydration.
So if you google persisting/hydrating redux. You should find the tools and articles you need.

Here's one I found that looks okay.
https://medium.com/@jrcreencia/persisting-redux-state-to-local-storage-f81eb0b90e7e

Comment: I guess I should either re-ask the question, because I am using [redux-persist](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-persist), which I thought was taking care of that. I checked in the __devtools>application>storage>localStorage__ and I see under Key: `persist:primary` and Value: ` {"isLoggedIn":"true","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}` and this on the bottom `{isLoggedIn: "true", _persist: "{"version":-1,"rehydrated":true}"}
isLoggedIn: "true"
_persist: "{"version":-1,"rehydrated":true}"`

Comment: If you manage to throw this into https://codesandbox.io in the next hr or so. I will check back and fork it to a working state for you.

A few tips:
1. Your constructor in App that is setting local state is pointless.
2. I would connect() the private route component to do it's own state lookup

Comment: Sorry for the delay! And thanks for your insight and help! I had a three-year old to put to bed, and then I passed put!
Question: Do I just need to add **just** the `index.js` file? The one with the routes? Or should I add the whole app?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Add as much as you can to have it functioning

Comment: Wow thanks for introducing me to codesandbox.io its amazing! I was literally able to just add my github repo to a sandbox!? This is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hillfinder-k8psw) to what I set up on condesandbox

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz So I noticed a couple of things.
First off... You should initialise your store in store/index.js ... You also need to run export const persistor = persistStore(store); in the same file ... Then export both to your _app.js and use that store in your provider and get rid of the persistor in the app constructor ... The point of persist gate is to block the rendering of your main UI until your store has been hydrated. So having component as the loading value defeats the purpose ... Have a loading placeholder instead so component can properly mount.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Also your import of withReactRouter is incorrect. Don't include file extensions in the import syntax